# What screwdriver size is needed for MacBook Pro mid 2012 back cover?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

What screwdriver size is needed for MacBook Pro mid 2012 back cover?

According to [iFixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-Teardown/4990/1#s22437) the Philips #00 should be used for the "lower case". Is the lower case a synonym for the "back cover"?

Comment: Since there is a lot of confusion on the model, uploading a picture of the screw sure would clarify everyone’s questions whether this is a pentalobe or a Phillips tool that is needed. Since your title says 2012 and the ificit says 2011 there’s no clear way to answer. I’ve made the question title match the accepted answer and closed it till we can be sure what is what.

Comment: @bmike, I've rolled back your edit because... Both the 13" and 15" Mid 2012 MacBook Pro have Philips screws on the lower case however the 15" Mid 2012 MacBook Pro with Retina has Pentalobe screws. Because the accepted answer show Philips screws it's a good assumption that the OP has the non Retina display and hence the Philip screws. Additionally I do not believe this question should be placed on hold since it has an accepted answer that has 7 upvotes.

Comment: @bmike, The original OP stated "MacBook Pro" **not**  "MacBook Pro Retina" so please see:  [MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2012 Hard Drive Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10378), [MacBook Pro 15" Unibody Mid 2012 Hard Drive Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10761) and [MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display Mid 2012 SSD Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+SSD+Replacement/9706)

Comment: @user3439894 Would you be game to edit the selected answer so all the other people can know this is answered? I'd be happy to reopen based on your good edit. I"m curious why you didn't link to the correct iFixit in your edit above (or does the 2011 and 2012 share the same 2011 tear down?)

Comment: @bmike, I feel that an answer marked as accepted (green √) and has 7 upvotes, it's plainly clear the question is answered. Also since the original OP stated "MacBook Pro mid 2012" and not mentioning Retina, it's already clear. Additionally, the OP made a comment to Elias Hedbäck's answer saying "No, the screws on the MacBook Pro mid 2012 back cover is Phillips #00 screws." So in spite of the link to a 2011 Teardown I'd say 2012 was correct and not a typo since the OP repeated it. IMO The confusion is those who have a Retina not paying attention to the fact that the OP never stated Retina.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate the assistance @user3439894

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

The back cover is secured with Philips #00 screws.

Note that is says:

> The lower case is secured by **ten** Phillips #00 screws.

You can see the ten screws on the back cover:

- four each at the top/bottom
- one each on the left/right

Answer (score 1):

Its a pentalobe on the Mid 2012 Macbook Pro retina.  Just purchased Torx and Phillips screwdriver sets based on how to's. Neither phillips 00 or Torx T6 work.  Where to find the Pentalobe set next.  I just want to upgrade the ram not open a repair shop.

Comment: Are you certain the OP has a retina Mac? The question links to a non-retina tear down as does the accepted answer. You are correct that retina models need asymmetrical / specialized drivers, but that might be an edit / caution on the selected answer and not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have a 15” mid-2012 MacBook Pro retina (A1398) and it’s definitely a pentalobe. A Phillips or Torx WILL NOT work.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of confusion here, and I’m not sure that questionnaire will ever upload a picture  Perhaps you could edit your answer showing pictures and specify how to determine which 2012 MacBook has which.

Comment: Actually, I edited the title since the iFixit tear down link was a 2011 model and not 2012 model.

Comment: Both the 13" and 15" Mid 2012 MacBook Pro have Philips screws on the lower case however the 15" Mid 2012 MacBook Pro with Retina has Pentalobe screws. Because the accepted answer show Philips screws it's a good assumption that the OP has the non Retina display and hence the Philip screws.

Answer (score -1):

The screws are pentalobes and should not be mixed by Philips or torx. If you usa a torx screwdriver you will damage the screws and in worst case you'll make them flat and you will not be able to unscrew them.

More info on pentalobes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentalobe_screw

Comment: No, the screws on the MacBook Pro mid 2012 back cover is Phillips #00 screws. I don't know about later models, I know about this one :)