# Philips #00 screwdriver for MacBook Pro 2013 NZ does not fit

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair

I need to remove the back plane of an early 2013 MacBook Pro, sold in New Zealand.

According to questions on here: 
[What screwdriver size is needed for MacBook Pro mid 2012 back cover?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/56515/132798)
[Screwdriver for 13-inch MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/113265/132798)

I need a Philips #00 screwdriver, which I bought as part of this set:

https://www.mitre10.co.nz/shop/fuller-mini-ratchet-screwdriver-set-12-piece-black-and-yellow/p/125687?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6r23zfPW2wIVlY2PCh0H7QxNEAQYCCABEgKXaPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

However, the screwdriver doesn't fit. Specifically it seems the blades of it are actually to thick to get into the screws.

Is this something I can specify as part of the screwdriver to look for? Or is size #00 possibly different in different parts of the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen occasional mismatches in sets for $20 in the US and certainly some really bad $10 sets in the US. Not knowing the relative prices I don't know if that's expensive for New Zealand. My gold standard is a wiha tool.

- https://www.kctoolco.com/wiha-26100-00-x-40mm-precision-phillips-screwdriver/ for $5 US

I would get a good tool for the ones you'll use a lot like #00 and if you can afford it - [a nice set](https://www.kctoolco.com/wiha-26197-7-piece-precision-slotted-phillips-screwdriver-set/). Another gold standard seller for me in the US is DigiKey Electronics: Here's [their #00 Phillips selection](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/tools/screw-and-nut-drivers/239?FV=5800045%2Cffe000ef&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&pageSize=25&pkeyword=phillips%2000)

Hopefully this lets you evaluate if you got a dud blade or just a low quality set in general. If it's really not able to fit - contact your seller to get advice if you can.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make  sure this is a budget problem not something I don't understand. I'll likely be able to pick up a Wiha cheap in Germany in a couple of weeks, shipping any of these is not worth it, as I likely won't use it again

Comment: Yes - it's pretty likely if the drive won't fit, it's just a bad piece of metal - bad being the tolerance to which it was machined or forged.

Comment: @mike - doesn't the early 2013 MacBook Pro use the [pentalobe screws](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2013+AirPort+Board+Replacement/17044) on the bottom cover?    Wiha makes this one too and it (and Klien tools) are my reach-for in my tool box....

Comment: +1 from me just for recommending Wiha ;) I also use some of their larger stuff for wood/metal-working too & it's virtually indestructible.

Comment: @mike - the ones sold here in NZ at that time were still Philips